# createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not creating a new document in firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a new user in Firebase. I am using the `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method but it does not create a new entry in the firebase db.

Here is my code:

```
final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: email,
  password: password,
);

if (newUser != null) {
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const VerifyEmailScreen()),
  );
} else {
  setState(() {
    registrationFail = true;
  });
}
```

I get an error message "An undefined error happened" which is the default error message in the catch code and then it just hangs.

I'm not sure I am communicating with Firebase. How do I check to see if I am talking to the db?

I have searched for a solution but everything is very old and nothing works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To troubleshoot this issue, you can re-check the following setup carefully.

1. Ensure that you have correctly placed the `google-services.json` file within your project directory.

```
PROJECT_ROOT_FOLDER > android > app > google-services.json
```

2. Ensure that you've initialized the Firebase configuration in your `main.dart`.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(); // Initialize firebase here
  
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: YourAppHomePage(), // Replace with your app's home page
    ),
  );
}
```

3. Handle error with try-catch:

```
try {
  final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email,
    password: password,
  );

  if (newUser != null) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const VerifyEmailScreen()),
    );
  } else {
    setState(() {
      registrationFail = true;
    });
  }
} catch (e) {
  // Handle the specific error
  print("Error creating user: $e");
  setState(() {
    registrationFail = true;
  });
}
```

*It helps to understand the issue.*

4. **Additional:** Not necessary in the Authentication case but please ensure Firestore Database or Cloud Firestore rules are not preventing the write operation. It should be like:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

You can find your entry here:
[image: Authentication Dashboard]

Hope your code will run as you expected.

Comment: Let me know if nothing works for you.

Comment: That worked. Thank you

Comment: @LostTexan Help by contributing to others by upvoting & accepting answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` API exists on Firebase Authentication, not in Cloud Firestore. So it creates a new record for the user in Firebase Authentication, but won't create anything in Firestore.

If you want to write to Firestore, check **its** API docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart).

If you're getting an error message that is vague, it might be that [email enumeration protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection) is enabled on your project - which intentionally hides a lot of detail from API responses to prevent against attacks. To see if this is the case, you may want to temporarily [disable the protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection#disable) and see if you get a clearer error message.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that. I have not used Firebase for a while. I am still not getting any response.